# Что не так? И почему в этих методах при попытке вывести на экран - ничего не выводится?

Tags: java

`String multiply(String s)` - возвращает строку повторенную 5 раз.

`String multiply(String s, int count)` - возвращает строку повторенную `count` раз.

```
public static String multiply(String s) {

    String result = "";     
    int res = Integer.parseInt(result);
    res = 0;

    while(res <= 5){
        res++;
    }
    return result;    
}

public static String multiply(String s, int count) {
        String result = "";  
        int res = Integer.parseInt(result);
        res *= count;
        return result;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(multiply("string"));
}
```

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что System.out.print ничего не выводит, потому что его нет в коде?

Comment: На данный момент нету. Но он тут и не нужен. Просто когда я его писал, он ничего не выводил будто его нету. Главная задача это возвращение строк.

Comment: В методе вы создаете переменную `String result = "";` дальше с ней НИЧЕГО не делаете и возвращаете её :) а переменную переданную на вход вы и вовсе игнорируете) ну и вообще, строки в java иммутабельны, поэтому в `return` явно должно стоять что-то другое. Подумайте что именно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как то так:

```
 public static String multiply(String s, int count) {
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        result += s;

    return result;
}

public static String multiply(String s) {
    return multiply(s, 5);
}
```

Comment: Супер! Во я лох:(( Когда же я начну разбираться)))